# Keras Transfer Learning weights = None and trainable = 'False'

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am new to transfer learning(tensorflow = 2.x ). In tutorials of a course we used weights = 'None', This means we are randomly initialzing the weights. Also in the same tutorial it was said that we set layers.trainable = False. So, my question is how will our model learn? Any help is useful. Thankyou
Also i am using InceptionV3.

Comment: Could be good to post the tutorial and/or some code. Potentially, e.g. for image classification, you might import InceptionV3 except leave off the "top" layer. In this case, you're keeping the "visual cortex," all the CNN layers constant, and you create new dense layers to learn the classification for your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

The model will not learn. The weights will be initialized randomly. Since layers in Inception model are set to be not trainable they will stay frozen at their initial levels. I recommend you selected the weights as "imagenet". This will make use of the pre-trined weights the model learned from processing the imagenet data set. Set include_top=False  and set pooling='max'. Then add a dense layer. The number of nodes in the dense layer should be equal to the number of classes you have.

Comment: so random weights are bad? the fit we do in this model is for just dense layer? Using imagenet will improve my accuracy?

Comment: It is best to use the imagenet weights because the network will all ready be "trained" to process images. If you set the InceptionV3 layers to not be trainable then you will just be training the dense layers. This should result in reasonable accuracy depending on the nature of your images. I usually allow the model to train all layers but this increases the amount of computation. If you do not have a GPU training could take a long time.

Comment: so  we are just training dense layer, and CNN layers are with random weights. Thank you so much it clears my concept. However i am surprised by accuracy given by these random weights. its so good .

Comment: Something does not make sense. If you did not use the imagnet weights and did not allow the the allow training of the inception model layers I can't see how you could get any reasonable   level of accuracy. It would help if you showed your training data.

Comment: its the kaggle cats-v-dogs dataset of images